# write numbers with pyautogui (not numpad numbers) or another lybrary

Tags: python, keyboard, emulation, pyautogui

I have a fishing game that to fish you have to press the number they tell you, it doesn't let you use the numpad keys and you can only use normal numbers, I tried to make a python script to automate it but when trying to press the key they say with pyautogui doesn't work, I think it's because it emulates a numpad number but I'm not sure because I don't know how to check it, but I know that if it writes the number in the game because when it emulates the number on the keyboard I'm on the mobile that's in the game Well, yes, it is written, if it is true that pyautogui emulates numpad numbers, I would like to know if there is any way to emulate numbers that are not from the numpad (those that are above the letters)

```
import pyautogui

key="2"

pyautogui.press(key)             #didnt work
pyautogui.press("num"+key)       #didnt work

pyautogui.keyDown(key)           #didnt work
pyautogui.keyDown("num"+key)     #didnt work

pyautogui.typewrite(key)         #didnt work
pyautogui.typewrite("num"+key)   #didnt work
```

Comment: are you talking about the numbers on the number pad at the side of the keyboard compared to the numbers on the top row ?   ...if so, then pyautogui will not be able to distinguish those because it sees the "number".

Comment: Yes, i want to emulate the numbers on the top row. If i cant with pyautogui do u think i  can do it with another package?

Comment: i doubt it because the keyboards are designed in a way that they send signals to the cpu and the signal for any given key is its asci representation: https://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: acsii tables explained here: https://sites.google.com/d/1PRs5NEVgILHQI7bxWg8LMZnRROh93zSA/p/10-RJnCrp6C5QfKh3vtIfbaDeyCsMxT0p/edit

Comment: IK but in game, when i press the number in the numpad it dont work and when i do it with the numbers of the top row it works

Comment: With a python library "pynput" I can see the keys that I press, and indeed the 2 key does not have the same value as the 2 of the numpad

Comment: you might have the num lock switched off on the keyboard !!!

Comment: bro..  nope, when i type "1" is "1" and when i type it in the numpad is <97>,

Answer (score 0):

if you run this code, you will see that the keypad numbers are different with the keypad on / off. This works for windows, there are alternatives for other operating systems (so it depends which op system you are using).

```py
import msvcrt

for i in range(10):
    key = msvcrt.getch().decode('utf-8')
    print(f"Key press {i+1}: {key}")
```

...but where they are different, this detects.

Here is a basic `pyautogui` version so that you can observe the key presses. Note that they do work (windows) on the keypad when it is switched on (number lock on).

```py
import pyautogui

i = 1
while True:
    key = pyautogui.prompt("Enter a key: ")
    print(f"Key press {i}: {key}")
    i += 1
    if key == "q":
        break
```